# Invoking of destructors in C++

Tags: c++, destructor

The following piece of code has a user defined data type called `String`.Objects of this class store a char pointer `str`(short hand for string) and `length`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class String
{
    char* str;
    int length;
public:
    String(){}                     //default constructor 
    String(const char* s)
    {
        length=strlen(s);
        str=new char[length+1];   
        strcpy(str,s);
    }
    void add(String a,String b)   //function to concatenate strings
    {
        length=a.length+b.length;
        str=new char[length+1];
        strcpy(str,a.str);
        strcat(str,b.str);
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<str<<endl;
    }
    ~String()                                //destructor 
    {
        delete str;
        cout<<"Destructor invoked!";
    }
};
int main()
{
    String s1;
    String s2("Well done!");
    String s3("Boy");
    s1.add(s2,s3);
    s1.display();
    s2.display();
    s3.display();
}
```

Output:

```
Destructor invoked!Destructor invoked!Well done!boy
X!!;
<!!;
Destructor invoked!Destructor invoked!Destructor invoked!
```

- It appears as though the destructor is invoked even before the
  `display` functions get invoked.Why is this?

If the destructor function were not defined, I get the following output(as expected):

```
Well done!boy
Well done!
boy
```

- Why is this unexpected output upon defining a destructor?

Comment: The destructor is called because the arguments of `add` are destroyed.

Comment: And your class is not Rule-of-3 compliant. You need to add at least copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: You have both memory leaks *and* double deletes. Look at `add`, and [what is the rule of three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: `delete str` should be `delete[] str;` - Also you have a memory leak in `add`

Comment: You also need to initialize members in the default constructor.

Comment: @user7852: Apparently you noted a problem with my answer and removed the selection of it as solution. What was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This default constructor

```
String(){}
```

doesn't initialize anything, because the two data members are of fundamental types and a fundamental type doesn't provide automatic initialization.

Any use of the resulting instance will therefore use indeterminate values (of the data members), and will therefore have Undefined Behavior.

Fix: initialize the data members.

---

You also need to take charge of copying and moving, e.g. to avoid double `delete`s – which is also Undefined Behavior.

The example code copies `String` instances in the call

```
s1.add(s2,s3);
```

… because `add` takes the arguments by value.

Fix: define at least a copy constructor.

---

In the destructor the deallocation

```
delete str;
```

… does not match the allocation of `str`, which used `new[]`.

It can work in practice, but it's Undefined Behavior and therefore can cause all sorts of issues.

Fix: use `delete[]` for something created with `new[]`.

---

After fixing the above the code will still *leak memory*. A simple fix could be to define a concatenating constructor, let `add` use that to create a new `String` instance, and then `swap` the states of that instance and the current instance. This approach has the advantage of automatically (well, almost automatically) being exception safe.

---

General advice:

- Instead of `<cstring>`, just use `<string.h>`. One advantage is that like the C header of the same name, it guarantees to place the names in the global namespace. So if you use unqualified names like `strcpy` it will work portably, not just by happenchance for the compiler at hand.
- Instead of passing potentially large objects *by value*, as in `void add(String a,String b)`, pass them by *reference to `const`*, as in `void add(String const& a,String const& b)`, to avoid needless copying.
- Preferentially don't do i/o, like the `void display()` member function, in a class that isn't concerned with i/o. For example, the `display()` function won't work in a graphical user interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need copy constructor for this: `void add(String a,String b);`
It's better to pass strings by reference:

```
void add(const String &a, const String &b);
```

Also in destructor you need to free the memory with delete[].

```
delete[] str;
```

Now it will work.

Comment: Re "Now it will work.", no, the code still has UB after just adding a copy constructor.